# Build IOS project with GDX library

Tags: java, ios, libgdx, gdx-pay

[image]I have a Gradle project. It's written in Java 17. I have the Java 17 JDK installed. I tried running the project on Gdx's DesktopLauncher and it worked fine. But when using the build on IOS, I get an unknown error. What's going on here and how can I fix it?